# How to use Nifi QueryRecord to lookup for values in a flowfile?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a scenario where a flowfile contains the json transformed, I need to now combine fields that are in the json, for example, I want to get the R and PA from the Original.ScoreInfo.Team per ID and get Enriched.Team.Source.HV and Enriched.Team.SourceMapped.HV based on the Team.ID. My desired json looks like:

```
[{
     TeamID: 1000,
     ValueR: 3, 
     ValuePA: 13},
{
     TeamID: 2000,
     ValueR: 1, 
     ValuePA: 14}
]
```

Flowfile example:

```
    [
  {
    "Mapping": {
      "ScoreInfo": {
        "Team": [
          {
            "ID": 1,
            "Source": {
              "HV": 1,
              "ID": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "ID": 3,
            "Source": {
              "HV": 2,
              "ID": 3
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "Original": {
      "ScoreInfo": {
        "Team": [
          {
            "HV": 1,
            "ID": 1,
            "R": 1,
            "PA": 8,
            "H": 2,
            "BB": 2,
            "SB": 0,
            "E": 0,
            "Score": [
              {
                "Inn": 1,
                "TB": 2,
                "R": 0,
                "H": 0,
                "BB": 1
              },
              {
                "Inn": 2,
                "TB": 2,
                "R": 1,
                "H": 2,
                "BB": 1
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "HV": 2,
            "ID": 3,
            "R": 1,
            "PA": 10,
            "H": 3,
            "BB": 0,
            "SB": 0,
            "E": 0,
            "Score": [
              {
                "Inn": 1,
                "TB": 1,
                "R": 1,
                "H": 2,
                "BB": 0
              },
              {
                "Inn": 2,
                "TB": 1,
                "R": 0,
                "H": 0,
                "BB": 0
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "MatchValue": "99999999",
    "Enriched": {
      "Team": [
        {
          "ID": 1,
          "Source": {
            "HV": 1,
            "ID": 1
          },
          "SourceMapped": {
            "HV": 1000,
            "ID": 1000
          }
        },
        {
          "ID": 2,
          "Source": {
            "HV": 2,
            "ID": 2
          },
          "SourceMapped": {
            "HV": 2000,
            "ID": 2000
          }
        }
      ],
      "MatchValue": "99999999"
    }
  }
]
```

I was trying to do it using the [QueryRecord](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryRecord/index.html) and combined with the RPATH but it is returning empty when try this `SELECT * FROM FLOWFILE WHERE RPATH(Original, '/ScoreInfo/Team/ID') = RPATH(Enriched, '/Team/ID')`

Any idea how can I use the QueryRecord to do it?

Comment: It's quite hard to tell because the example source JSON you provided isn't valid JSON - can you please update with valid source JSON?

Comment: Sorry @Sdairs, I copy and paste again the JSON. Thanks